# How to get current model for a route from a controller or a view?

Tags: ember.js

I want to implement item-list/item-detail pattern in Ember, but the nuance is that the detail view must appear next to the selected item. E.g:

```
<ul>
    <li><div>Post 1<div></li>
    <li><div>Post 2<div></li>
    <li><div>Post 3<div></li>
    <li>
        <div>Post 4<div>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>Comment 1</li>
                <li>Comment 2</li>
                <li>Comment 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><div>Post 5<div></li>
</ul>
```

The Handlebars template I tried is:

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='posts'>
    <ul>
        {{#each model}}
            {{#linkTo 'post' this}}
                <div>{{title}}</div>
            {{/linkTo}}
            {{#if isSelected}} <!-- How to implement isSelected ? -->
                <div>{{!-- render selected post's comments --}}</div>
            {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

I tried this in controller:

```
App.PostController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    isSelected: function() {
        return this.get('content.id') === /* what to put here? */;
    }
});
```

What I'm stuck with is how to implement `isSelected` in 'Ember'-way? Am I going in right direction?

Comment: by clicking on post you want to show its comments?am i got you?

Comment: yes, I want to show comments and probably other post details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track. The trick is to use a different controller to wrap products in the item-list vs. the item-detail. So start by specifying that the handlebars `{{each}}` helper should wrap each entry in a `ListedProductController`

```
{{#each model itemController="listedProduct"}}
```

Now define `ListedProductController`, adding the `isSelected` function you'd been writing. Now it can reference the singleton `ProductController` via the `needs` array, comparing the product that was set by the router to the listed product.

```
App.ProductController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({});
App.ListedProductController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['product'],
  isSelected: function() {
    return this.get('content.id') === this.get('controllers.product.id');
  }.property('content.id', 'controllers.product.id')
});
```

I've posted a working example here: http://jsbin.com/odobat/2/edit

Comment: OMG, this works, but it is very confusing to me. Do you have refs to dig more on this?

Comment: Here's an article that might be relevant - http://blog.gaslight.co/post/54512786990/intermediate-ember-controller-concepts